# orderBy not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting

I am trying to iterate over a JSON response and sort by another key-value pair in the object (the order object value, but looks like that is now working out for me.

Can I reformat the object in another way that I could not think of so far?

I there anything that I can do in Angular?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in myCards">
        <h1>Title: {{item.title}}</h1>

        <div ng-repeat="(blockName, majorBlock) in item.blocks | orderBy:'order'">
            <h2>Name: {{blockName}}, Order: {{majorBlock.order}}</h2>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.myCards =  {
            template: {
                tagline: 'Tagline',
                url: 'url',
                title: 'My Title',
                blocks: {
                    'cover': {
                        "coverUrl": "http://www.url.com/cover/",
                        "coverImage": "http://www.url.com/cover/",
                        "order": '1'
                    },
                    'text': {
                        "headerText": "amet anim est eu enim in incididunt cillum reprehenderit proident",
                        "order": '2'
                    },
                    'products_block': {
                        'order': '3'

                    }

                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fvdb3d3p/

I tried a few hacks, with orderByArray plugin, but they break the rest of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$scope.myCards.template.blocks` is an object, not an `Array`, you can iterate an object with `ng-repeat`, but the filter `orderby` only works with arrays, as you can see in the API documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

You may want to write a custom filter for this.

**EDIT**:

I've found this custom filter called "`orderObjectBy`" from: http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/

```
yourApp.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
  return function(items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

**EDIT:**

I've tweaked the original filter function so that you can have access to the `key` of your object, the tweaked version looks like this:

```
.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
  return function(items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item, key) {
      item.originalKey = key;
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
})
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/fvdb3d3p/2/

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately this script is changing my node names: http://jsfiddle.net/zped9wLs/

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu I just made an edit to the custom function, so that you can have access to the original key.

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu does this answer solve your question? If it does, please accept it, if it doesn't please explain why. Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate your help. Your solution works fine for the example I added here, but I am still having some problems with the dom & db update that are caused by this script. I was looking for a more robust solution. Anyways, if nobody will contribute to this questions for your I'll accept your answer. Thanks alot!